# How to run MySQL Query which has multiple lines in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How do you run a query like the following in PHP:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('example name', 'thisisfirstline
           thisissecondline
           thisisthirdline')
```

I have type set to text.

I have no problems at all when I run it with Navicat.
I tried running it in PHP:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('example name', 'thisisfirstline
           thisissecondline
           thisisthirdline') 
           OR die('ERROR');
```

This outputs the following:

```
thisisfirstlinethisissecondlinethisisthirdline
```

How do I insert the value without sticking it all together?

Comment: Probably this new row in mysql has newline characters, but your client does not show them correct way. Try to use mysql console to be shure - what exactly is in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\n` for inserting newline in a MySQL table :

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('example name', 'thisisfirstline\n
    thisissecondline\n
    thisisthirdline')
```

Answer (score 0):

make the type to `varchar` instead of `text` in table